KEDA can't connect with RABBITMQ service with TLS
I'm getting 509 error when trying to connect from my cluster to rabbitMQ that we have domain name my-domain.domain.private, and we have the crt,key and ca from the server.
How can i fix this issue?
Error on keda-operator Cannot connect
2024-10-28T10:49:27Z    ERROR   Reconciler error    {"controller": "scaledobject", "controllerGroup": "keda.sh", "controllerKind": "ScaledObject", "ScaledObject": {"name":"rabbitmq-scaledobject","namespace":"my-service-ns"}, "namespace": "my-service-ns
", "name": "rabbitmq-scaledobject", "reconcileID": "40af3bf9-6990-4420-832b-6dcfdeb2521d", "error": "error establishing rabbitmq connection: tls: failed to verify certificate: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority"}

The code in my deployment that should define the scale object with using secret and trigger authentecation
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: keda-rabbitmq-secret
  namespace: my-service-ns
data:
  host: my-host in base64
  tls: ZW5hYmxl enable in base64
  ca: ca in base64
  cert: cert in base64
  key: key in base64
---
apiVersion: keda.sh/v1alpha1
kind: TriggerAuthentication
metadata:
  name:trigger-auth-rabbitmq-conn
  namespace: my-service-ns
spec:
  secretTargetRef:
    - parameter: host
      name: keda-rabbitmq-secret
      key: host
    - parameter: tls
      name: keda-rabbitmq-secret
      key: tls
    - parameter: ca
      name: keda-rabbitmq-secret
      key: ca
    - parameter: cert
      name: keda-rabbitmq-secret
      key: cert
    - parameter: key
      name: keda-rabbitmq-secret
      key: key

---
apiVersion: keda.sh/v1alpha1
kind: ScaledObject
metadata:
  name: rabbitmq-scaledobject
  namespace: my-service-ns
spec:
  scaleTargetRef:
    name: {{ .Values.name }}
  minReplicaCount: 1
  maxReplicaCount: 15
  pollingInterval: 120  
  cooldownPeriod:  300
  triggers:
  - type: rabbitmq
    metadata:
      protocol: auto
      queueName: my_queue
      mode: QueueLength
      value: "20"
    authenticationRef:
      name:trigger-auth-rabbitmq-conn


